# Zend Framework Checkbox Decorators

Tags: php, zend-framework, checkbox, zend-form, zend-decorators

What I am trying to accomplish is to have checkbox labels display after checkbox input fields (to the right of them).

I am using these decorators now:

```
private $checkboxDecorators = array(
    Label,
    array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'checkbox')),
    'ViewHelper',
    array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'li')),
);
```

I have tried switching the Label and ViewHelper decorators but that did nothing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
$this->getElement('elementId')->addDecorator('Label', array('placement' => 'APPEND'))
```

the placement option can take APPEND or PREPEND as value

Comment: I needed that! Or you could use $this->getElement('elementId')->getDecorator('label')->setOption('placement', 'APPEND');

Answer (score 3):

I know that is an older question, but you can also use

```
$element->getDecorator('label')->setOption('placement', 'APPEND');
```

if it is an already created element with an existing decorator