# Zend Form Checkbox Element customization

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a zend form with some element on, including a check box.
It looks normal :

```
checkbox label []
```

I would like to add a link to the right making it look like this:

```
checkbox label [] thelink
```

I've tried the following, but instead of aligning horizontaly the description with the checkbox it puts it under it :

```
$boolean->setDescription('desc');
        $boolean->setDecorators(array(
            'ViewHelper',
            'Description',
            'Errors',
            array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd')),
            array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt')),
        ));
```

I'm a begginer with Zend Forms. Any idea how could i implement this?

Thank you

Comment: I think you might need a [decorator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.form.decorators.html). Have a look at the accepted answer of [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158671/zend-framework-checkbox-decorators), I think it might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Try changing the styles(width, float, etc.) of the dd tag. `$element->getDecorator('HtmlTag')->setOption('style', 'width:20px;');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

Here's how i did it:

```
  $boolean->setDescription('description');
        $boolean->setDecorators(array(
            'ViewHelper',
            'Description',
            'Errors',
            array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd')),
            array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt')),
            array('Description', array('escape' => false, 'tag' => '', 'placement' => 'append')),
        ));
```